# I need to plan for disaster recovery for my AWS Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, recovery

I was thinking what if My AWS Account get deleted/inaccessible one fine day? (may sound weird). Have anyone implemented any solution for this? Can we have back from one AWS account to another AWS account?

Comment: This is probably not the best place to ask this question, since it’s not about programming. http://serverfault.com/ is probably better. So don’t be discouraged if this question gets downvoted and closed and deleted. Come back and ask more programming questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do, one is to make sure you have at least two administrator accounts, one that you use, and one that you store away in a safe place and only use for emergencies.

The second is to setup a completely seperate AWS account as a 'backup', with its own set of credentials. You can grant cross-account access from your primary account, to your backup account but only allow the primary account to 'put' or backup objects to the backup account, so that even if your primary account is compromised, the attacker can't do harm to the second account from the primary  account.

The actual process to backup your services on one account to another is going to vary depending on which services you are using, but the concept is the same - backup the data to s3 and then copy the data from s3 in your primary account to s3 in the backup account - and make sure the primary account only has enough access to the second account to 'put' things, not delete. Nobody in your company should have access to both of those sets of credentials (assuming your company is not tiny).

You don't want to be this company that was put out of business when there account was compromised:

https://threatpost.com/hacker-puts-hosting-service-code-spaces-out-of-business/106761/

Also, this video, from AWS Reinvent 2015 (starting around 50 minutes in), listen to how AirBNB protects against these issues in just this way:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHg8LD5KNC0

Answer (score -1):

Finally After lot of reasearch and help from **Skeddly**, I found a solution for Linux machines.
Via [Skeddly](http://www.skeddly.com/) we can copy EBS snapshots to another AWS account hassle free.It works brilliant.Now even if my Primary AWS account is compromised, I have all EBS snapshots to start with by BCP AWS account for linux machines ;)
Now am hunting for windows machine solution for which I already got an idea... ;)